# How to use Jboss with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, spring-boot

I am learning Spring Boot and wanted to know if there is any way to use Jboss as application server using gradle.

Greetings

Comment: Are you looking to embed jboss or have a war to be deployed?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I think the first would be good to know jboss embedded as it is like Spring Boot manages web servers (Tomcat and Jetty).